# IFrame - Exibição vídeos do youtube

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Bom dia gente, Gostaria de um auxílio, preciso exibir últimos vídeos do canal do youtube no site.

Este código que utilizei funcionou, após o carregamento da página, ele exibe os últimos cinco vídeos:

```js
<div class="video">
                <script>
                    var htmlString = "";
                    var apiKey = 'minhaAPI'; //https://console.developers.google.com
                    var channelID = 'MeuCanal';
                    var maxResults = 999;

                    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=' + apiKey + '&channelId=' + channelID + '&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=' + (maxResults > 1 ? 5: maxResults), function(data) {
                        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                            var videoID = item['id']['videoId'];
                            var title = item['snippet']['title'];
                            var videoEmbed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID;
                            htmlString += '<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="' + videoEmbed + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                        });
                        $('.video').html(htmlString);
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
```

**Porém, acontece o seguinte:**

A página carrega inteira, depois some todo o conteúdo e somente aparece os iframes dos cinco vídeos que solicitei.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar sobre como posso fazer, estes vídeos aparecerem somente numa section ou div específica, sem tomar conta do site todo, e sumir com todo o conteúdo original da página?

Agradeço muito pela ajuda, desde já!